# PTIJ: Why did Pharaoh's baker like Harry Potter?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Breishit 40:16 says:

וַיַּ֥רְא שַׂר־הָאֹפִ֖ים כִּ֣י ט֣וֹב פָּתָ֑ר

The head of the baking saw that Potter was good.

Was Harry Potter in the jail with Joseph, the wine steward and the baker? If so, what was he doing there? If not, how did the baker know about Harry Potter, and why did he think he was "good"?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

> נִצְנְצָה בוֹ רוּחַ הַקֹּדֶשׁ

The baker saw in Ruach Hakodesh that (Harry) Potter is good, and this goodness can and will be used against him through dreams. As it is said in the heiligeh Book 5, "Harry Potter and The Order of The Phoenix":

> Lucius Malfoy: "Oh, you don’t know Potter as I do, Bellatrix. He has a great weakness for heroics; the Dark Lord understands this about him. Now give me the prophecy, Potter."
>   Harry Potter: "I know Sirius is here. I know you’ve got him!"
>   Lucius Malfoy: "It’s time you learned the difference between life and dreams, Potter. Now give me the prophecy, or we start using wands."

Comment: Downvoter, why? You don't like Harry potter that much? Is it because I called Book 5 "heiligeh"? Are you more of a Book 1 kind of person?